# Tableau wrong download (export) layout from server final user view

Tags: layout, server, download, export, tableau-api

I need some help with this issue. But first I should explain a little more of the use case.

I have a dashboard with 25 woksheets (graphs). Each worksheet is visible to the user, so if he wants to export a single graph, it should be possible. For achieve that, I think it may be an option to use the standard Download function in the server final user view, and select the wanted format (PowerPoint, PFD, etc). The dashboard size is 1400px (w) by 6100px (h) , and each worksheet has 1400px (w) by 400px (h)

When I try to export the worksheets (individually or not), or selecting them from the option "Export selected views", the layout of the graphics is wrong for the PowerPoint or PDF formats (too streched and thin). The user wants 1 worksheet per page, covering entire page.

I have to mention that when I do the same export in the edition mode on Server or Desktop, the export works well! Only works wrong in the web server user view.